# Why is House Rule XXVIII "Reserved"?

Tags: united-states, congress

In looking thorugh the official [Rules of the House of Representatives of the 114th Congress](http://clerk.house.gov/legislative/legprocess.aspx), I noticed that the next-to-last rule, XXVIII (28) was marked "Reserved" and has no text.

Why is this?  Why is the rule on General Provisions after this reserved rule (XXIX), and not the 28th rule on its own?

Comment: Same reason "Order 66" was listed as reserved in the Grand Army of the Republic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Clarification of the rule. The Gephardt rule would not, as I state below, automatically raise the debt limit, it would just have the House automatically send a joint resolution to the Senate to raise the debt limit. Not quite the catch all solution I've described below.

Okay now that I have enough rep I've changed the answer to include the history of the Gephardt Rule.

House Rule XXVIII used to be the "Gephardt Rule" and was repealed under the 112th Congress (https://www.fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R42395.pdf, pg. 49). The Gephardt rule "provid[ed] for the automatic engrossment of a joint resolution to adjust the public debt limit when a concurrent resolution on the budget was adopted by Congress." Meaning, whenever a budget was adopted the public debt limit was automatically raised to suit the budget. As the pdf I linked states: "This rule had allowed the House to avoid a direct vote on legislation to adjust the debt limit."

Gephardt rule... considering the dangerous posturing over the debt limit recently it sounds like a good idea. *Note: the 112th Congress operated from 2011-2013, the first congress after the Republic party took the majority in the House of Representatives.* Public spending was a large issue in that election so the repeal of this rule makes sense.

Not to say it had not been suspended in the past. A Congressional Research Service report in 2008: "In 11 of the 29 years since the Gephardt rule was established, the rule did not apply, due to its suspension or repeal by the House (calendar years 1988, 1990-1991, 1994-1997, and 1999-2002). In most cases, the House suspended the rule because the legislation changing the statuatory limit was not necessary; at the time, the existing public debt limit was expected to be sufficient (http://crs.wikileaks-press.org/RL31913.pdf: pg. 3)."

Now, back to your actual question... Why is it listed as reserved? Well, because the House said so. H. Res 5 (January 5, 2011) :

"(2) REQUIRING A VOTE ON RAISING THE DEBT LIMIT.----Rule XXVIII is amended to read as follows: "Rule XXVIII "(Reserved.)"." (https://www.congress.gov/112/bills/hres5/BILLS-112hres5eh.pdf pg. 9)

I'm assuming it was listed as reserved because this rule has been suspended/repealed and re-implemented quite a bit since its adoption. They've listed it as reserved probably because they know it will likely be re-implemented once again.

Comment: Nice answer!  I'd never heard of this rule before, but it makes a lot of sense to me.  And the reasoning for why to leave it "Reserved" instead of just removing it makes sense too.  Welcome to Politics.SE!

Comment: @Bobson Thanks! Strangely enough with all the debt ceiling politics that has happened over the past couple of years, I have never heard of this rule before either.

Comment: @Bobson I added an edit to the top of my post that clarifies the rule.

Comment: Great answer. But it would have helped if they put in a few more words to clarify the intent (e.g. "Reserved for the purpose of...").  Wonder if they simply couldn't be bothered to do so, or because any additional wording could be used for misconduct in the future.

Comment: @Sabuncu maybe they just couldn't be bothered to reorder the rest of the rules...ha! Maybe they know that it would be a bad *political* move at the moment to specify that the intent is to bring the Gephardt Rule back so they are leaving it unstated. Or, maybe I'm completely wrong. I couldn't find any confirmation whatsoever that it is actually being reserved specifically for the Gephardt Rule but it does make quite a bit of sense that it would be.

Comment: Amazing.  If it wasn't for the question here, and your answer, I don't think anyone would know about how they conduct their business.